# Samba Permissions

Tags: samba

I have Samba set up on a Fedora 15 Machine. All looks well except that there's something nagging and I don't know what exactly is causing it.

I have a public share on the server which is accessible by everyone and its permissions is set to 777. When one person opens a document under that share and closes it after working, the other person who opens it can't edit or save it because it opens in read only and shows that it's still open on another computer.

What might be causing this and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. I edited your question, feel free to revert the changes or edit it again.

Comment: When does the second person open the document? While the first one has it stil open, or only after the first one closed it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define [create mask](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#CREATEMASK) and perhaps the [force user](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#FORCEUSER) and/or [force group](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#FORCEGROUP) options for that share in `smb.conf`.

Comment: Thank you soo much. Im gonna try it and see if it works.